# Delete row of a dataframe condition

Tags: dataframe

here is my first dataframe `df1`

```
    269     270    271  346
0     1  153.00   2.14    1
1     1  153.21   3.89    2
2     1  153.90   2.02    1
3     1  154.18   3.02    1
4     1  154.47   2.30    1
5     1  154.66   2.73    1
6     1  155.35   2.82    1
7     1  155.70   2.32    1
8     1  220.00  15.50    1
9     0  152.64   1.44    1
10    0  152.04   2.20    1
11    0  150.48   1.59    1
12    0  149.88   1.73    1
13    0  129.00   0.01    1
```

here is my second dataframe `df2`

```
    269      270    271  346
0     0   149.88    2.0    1
```

I would like the row at the index 12 to be remove because they have the same number in columns `['269']` & `['270']`

Answer (score 0):

Hope below solutions would match to your requirement

1. Using `anti_join` from `dplyr`

`library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("269", "270"))`

2. Using `%in%` operator

`df1[!(df1$269 %in% df2$269 & df1$270 %in% df2$270),]`